# Word for a person who acts super nice to you to impress others, but he doesn't actually mean it?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a person who acts super nice to you to impress others and build his image, but in real life, he doesn't actually mean it?

For example, what would you call Cindrella's stepmom who treats her well in front of her dad, however, when he dies she makes Cindrella do chores?

I need this word to describe a ruler who is just pretending to protect his people for the sake of his image and doesn't really care about whatever happens to them.

Answer (score 0):

Among the many synonyms you may easily find online for the related concept of a *hypocrite* is the word *dissembler*. I believe this is one of the best to fit your description.

> To dissemble
>
> To hide your real intentions and feelings or the facts
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dissemble?q=Dissembled)